# mirror a site with wget that only response with gzip

Tags: wget, gzip, nginx

I'm trying to mirror a site but the server only responses with gzip pages so wget won't recurse. I've searched around and there are some references to a patch to add gzip support to wget however they seem to be out of date. Is there anyway to do this? If not I was considering reverse proxying it through nginx.

Comment: Have you already tried sending `Accept-Encoding: identity` in the HTTP request header?

Comment: Yes to no effect

Comment: Do you have to use wget? This may be easier to do with Perl/Python/Ruby, all of which have easy-to-use http retrieval and html parsing libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 4 ways:

1. `wget` one page, `gunzip` it and process it again from the html... iterate until finished:

   ```
   wget -m http://example.org/page.html
   find . -name \*gz -exec gzip -d {} \;
   find . -name \*html -exec wget -M -F {} \;</code></pre>
   ```

   This will be slow, but should work.
2. Install Privoxy and configure it to uncompress the requested pages:

   > +prevent-compression
   >
   > Prevent the website from compressing the data. Some websites do that, which is a problem for Privoxy when built without zlib support, since +filter and +gif-deanimate will not work on compressed data. Will slow down connections to those websites, though.
3. Privoxy or another proxy might also be able to get the compressed pages and deliver the uncompressed copy to the client; Google for it.
4. My `wget` wont send the "Accept-Encoding: gzip" header that requests `gzip` content... Check why yours does it. Maybe you have a proxy that is adding it?
   You can also use Privoxy to remove that header.

Comment: The wget example is likely going to be a bit more involved than that. Gzipped content doesn't automatically get a gz name. Then the subsequent find/wget might need to deal with any text/html content downloaded rather than `*.html`. Maybe via `--adjust-extension` but then recursion will be slow and you'd need to convert links which you can't because the download is gzipped... and so on.  A proxy that removes encodings will be easier. [Fiddler](https://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) will do it. privoxy should too if it's doing any filtering but `+prevent-compression` just modifies the header

Answer (score 2):

```
wget -m -q --compression=auto http://example.com
```

From the [GNU `wget` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html):

> `--compression=type`
>
> Choose the type of compression to be used.  Legal values are `auto`, `gzip` and `none`.
>
> If `auto` or `gzip` are specified, `wget` asks the server to compress the file using the `gzip` compression format. If the server compresses the file and responds with the `Content-Encoding` header field set appropriately, the
> file will be decompressed automatically.
>
> If `none` is specified, `wget` will not ask the server to compress the file and will not decompress any server responses. This is the default.
>
> Compression support is currently experimental. In case it is turned on, please report any bugs to "bug-wget@gnu.org".

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. I assumed it was `auto` by default, but setting it explicitly to `auto` did the trick. Might depend on wget version, mine is `1.20.3`.

Answer (score 1):

A belated response, but for purpose of web reference:

```
wget -O - $URL | zcat | wget -B $URL -i - -F -c -T 45 -k -r --page-requisites
```

"Known good" for documentation caching. The Timeout/Retry options (such as with -c and -T) may be useful with regards to intermittent "Link drops" in wireless networks. All options optional, of course.

Comment: https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=wget+-O+-+%24URL+%7C+zcat+%7C+wget+-B+%24URL+-i+-+-F+-c+-T+45+-k+-r+--page-requisites

Comment: this could be improved by using `zcat -f` so that it will handle non-compressed urls too.

Comment: This looks promising, but I haven't managed to get it working - it doesn't seem to save the original (base) page (since that is in stdout only?) and it's fetching links from <a href=""> tags, not just images & scripts. any ideas?